# R-plotly: Subplot shows only bottom plot

Tags: r, r-plotly

I would like to reproduce the "Scaled Subplots" in https://plot.ly/r/subplots/ for the `mtcars` data.

```
mtcars %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(am))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = ~qsec, color = ~factor(vs), yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  subplot(nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
```

Only the bottom subplot shows up:
[image: produced image with missing subplot]

I thought that I did faithfully copy/translated the code, but something must be wrong.
Of note, the subplot discriminates `am`, whereas the color discriminates `vs`.
I tried `am` for both the subplot and the color:

```
mtcars %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(am))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = ~qsec, color = ~am, yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  subplot(nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
```

It does not help much, but the two grids appear:
[image: other image with missing data]
On the latter example, I expected the `am==0` (blueish) dots to be in the top subplot.

Any suggestion?

```
packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘4.9.0’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this way here you can do this, but must create two plots and than use `subplot()`

```
p1 = mtcars %>%
      filter(am==0) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = ~qsec, color = ~vs, legendgroup = "am0", name = "0",
          type = "scatter" , mode = "markers", showlegend = FALSE)

p2 = mtcars %>%
      filter(am==1) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = ~qsec, color = ~vs, legendgroup = "am1", name = "1",
          type = "scatter" , mode = "markers")

subplot(p1,p2,nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE, which_layout = 1)
```

Here the output:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and sorry for being late).  However, my aim was to show `qsec` on the y-axis.  It seems that you cannot plot it since you removed it with your `select`.

Comment: Not exactly...  What you are plotting is the exact same points on the 2 plots, with different colors, right?  What I would like is: above, the cars where `am` is 0; below, the cars where `am` is 1.  Am I clear?

Comment: My bad, I forgot use of `filter()`

Comment: Maybe it can, but I do not know how to do it yet.

Comment: This does not work for ed plots (plot_ly, scattter3d). Any ideas?

Comment: @Adel I do not know how to build an subplot of 3d plots. Sorry....